# On Breaking In to A Subject Through Independent Study

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question, mathematical-physics, education

I am fairly confident that this question falls under "good subjective" per the help page--I am unsure of where else to go otherwise.

I'm hoping to start an academic career in HEPT/mathematical physics. I'm in my freshman year at a US flagship but am somewhat advanced (taking topology, complex analysis, familiar with the absolute basics of abstract algebra). And I'm having trouble getting anywhere, at least to my standards. As a firm believer that most of what separates the best from the average is experience, I'd like to spend as much time as I can working on blasting even further ahead in the subjects I love above almost anything else. Yet I find myself cranking out 150 hours in League of Legends in my first semester.

Some of that is probably a lack of consistent motivation. But some of that lack, I feel, stems from the absence of any sort of track to follow, no footsteps to trace. So I'm here.

Specifically, I'm here looking for people's stories, and recommendations. Side paths (mostly in the form of high-quality, plentifully-problemed texts), not to be made redundant by standard academic curricula, that I can follow to learn without the setback of constant googling of definitions I should have known prior to jumping into a text I close permanently at page 23. Paths to higher analysis, dynamical systems, ergodic theory, differential geometry, and anything else I'm too poorly exposed to know about that is of use/interest to the mathematically-minded physicist are more than welcome. But anything helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I always hate that kind of questions. I’d love to give references, but in my “early-university” system, the teachers’ lectures and problems were self-sufficient, and there was little need to go check a textbook. In your post, you’re telling us a lot about yourself (always good to give some context :) ) but little about what math you know. That limits the relevance of what I can give you.

Comment: Mostly, at “freshman level”, if you truly are interested in higher concepts, I would recommend a thorough tour of elementary real analysis (with the proofs and all, about converging sequences, continuity, differentiability, Landau notations, integral Taylor formulas) and then some linear algebra (preferably with the abstract “vector space” point of view foremost, with the matrices as a “visual help” — I think “Linear Algebra Done Right” does that). These are both fundamental and with very little prerequisites, so I hope you’ve not already covered them, else I might be running out of ideas. :)